# Is it possible to create AWS RDS server using juju?

Tags: juju, amazon-ec2, aws

I have created various AWS EC2 servers using juju for fast development. but i want to install MySQL Database in RDS Server instead of EC2, so is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use AWS RDS someone has to write a charm for that specific service.

I searched the charm store: https://jujucharms.com/store

and was not able to find a charm that will leverage RDS directly, you'd have to use a generic instance with either MySQL, Percona, or MariaDB.

If you're interested in modifying the existing MySQL charm to use RDS you can find documentation on how to do that here:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/authors-charm-writing

Any help providing RDS would be much appreciated!